# Qual é o erro de sintaxe em minha função?

Tags: python, revisão-de-código

```
def Grow_population_rate(year_1, year_2, City_name, pop_1, pop_2):
    pop_diff = pop_2 - pop_1
    year_diff = year_2 - year_1
    for pop_rate = pop_diff/year_diff * 100:
        return("The rate of population growth "+"City_name "+" in the year is "+str(pop_rate)+" %!")
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português. Por favor, leia a descrição da _tag_ [`revisão-de-código`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revis%c3%a3o-de-c%c3%b3digo), que coloca explicitamente que a tag deve ser usada somente em códigos que estão funcionando. Como você é novo no site, é normal você ainda não conhecer as regras do site, mas justamente por isso sugiro que você leia o [Guia de Sobrevivência do StackOverflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/69296), que lhe dará importantes instruções e informações sobre o funcionamento do SOpt. :)

Answer (score 1):

Carlos,

O `for` não está correto.

Acredito que o que você queira seja o abaixo.

```
def Grow_population_rate(year_1, year_2, City_name, pop_1, pop_2):
    pop_diff = pop_2 - pop_1
    year_diff = year_2 - year_1
    pop_rate = pop_diff/year_diff * 100:
    return("The rate of population growth "+"City_name "+" in the year is "+str(pop_rate)+" %!")
```

Nota: Modifiquei o mínimo possível.

**UPDATE**
Conforme mencionado em outra resposta, o `return` também está com problema

Usando fstring:

```
return(f"The rate of population growth {City_name} in the year is {str(pop_rate)}%!")
```

Espero que ajude.

Comment: Obrigado ajudou muito

Answer (score 1):

Olá tudo bem? Como o Paulo disse o laço for está errado, na verdade não precisa desse laço de repetição para fazer a atribuição da variável pop_rate, fazendo dessa forma:

```
pop_rate = pop_diff/year_diff * 100
```

Também notei que no teu retorno está dessa forma

```
return("The rate of population growth "+"City_name "+" in the year is "+str(pop_rate)+" %!")
```

Onde o paramêtro City_name da tua função está entre aspas, no caso na saida da função você vai ver invés do nome da cidade "City_name"

Sem contar que como você colocou essa mensagem no retorno da função, para visualizá-la você deve usar o método print nela ficando assim:

```
print(Grow_population_rate(parm1, param2, param3, param4, param5))
```

Para remover a necessidade do método print, sugiro  que você coloque ele dentro do corpo da função, e no retorno coloque apenas o pop_rate que pode ser usado futuramente e ficará oculto na saída, o código ficaria + ou - assim:

```
def Grow_population_rate(year_1, year_2, City_name, pop_1, pop_2):
    pop_diff = pop_2 - pop_1
    year_diff = year_2 - year_1
    pop_rate = pop_diff/year_diff * 100:
    print("The rate of population growth "+ City_name +" in the year is "+str(pop_rate)+" %!") 
    return pop_rate
```